# The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized https C# Web API Windows server

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-web-api2

I am consuming a Web API from a Webforms application on my local PC. It works correctly, I get to consume the API, however when I publish the Webforms application to the server, I get an error

> The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized

Let me tell you that the API works correctly with HTTP on the server but for security reasons it was requested to use HTTPS only, that's where I get the error that I mentioned.

Here I leave a fragment of the code where the consumption of the API is carried out.

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

// Throw new Exception("Demo error");

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");

    string respuestaERP = client.UploadString(urlApi, "POST", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param));
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResult>(respuestaERP);
}
```

When I add this line of code it works fine on my local PC but not on the server.

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate
```

Comment: The line of code you provided basically says that the `.NET Framework` should trust any `SSL/TLS Certificate` without checking its validity. The Error Code 401 (unauthorized) is related to authentication. So ensure that your credentials to authenticate to the WebAPI is correct. Which technology do you use for authentication?

Comment: The web application uses Windows authentication that captures the credentials of the user logged in on the PC.